# TableView Not Reloading when working with combine but working when applied delay using DispatchQueue.Main.asyncAfter

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, combine

`@Published var allJobs:[JobsModel] = []`
this will populate on response on api call

here is my subscriber Code

```
viewModel.$allJobs.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main ).sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
                case .finished:
                       print("finished")
                    break
                case .failure(let anError):
                    print(anError.localizedDescription)
                    break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { someValue in
            self.jobsTbl.reloadData()
            print(".sink() received \(someValue)")
        }).store(in: &cancellable)
```

this is not working when data is populated
but working when I add delays like

```
viewModel.$allJobs.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main ).sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
                case .finished:
                       print("finished")
                    break
                case .failure(let anError):
                    print(anError.localizedDescription)
                    break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { someValue in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01){
            self.jobsTbl.reloadData()
            }
            print(".sink() received \(someValue)")
        }).store(in: &cancellable)
```

Comment: You need to use `receive(on:)` not `subscribe(on:)` see the discussion here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/subscribe(on:options:)

Answer (score 0):

what you really want is receiving values from the main thread

```
viewModel.$allJobs.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
```

This's from [apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/receive(on:options:))

> You use the receive(on:options:) operator to receive results and completion on a specific scheduler, such as performing UI work on the main run loop.